# I can't understand what causes there errors

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

After installing packages using `npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server --save-dev`

The terminal gives me this error message:

```
➜  Projeto npm install webpack webpack-cli webpack-dev-server --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN projeto@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN projeto@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ webpack-dev-server@3.11.2
+ webpack-cli@4.7.0
+ webpack@5.38.1
updated 3 packages and audited 499 packages in 35.305s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
➜  Projeto material-ui
zsh: command not found: material-ui
➜  Projeto npm install @ material-ui / core
npm WARN deprecated material-ui@0.20.2: You can now upgrade to @material-ui/core
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/peter/.npm/_logs/2021-06-02T04_35_32_632Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is the exact command you are running? The only error is the part starting with "ERR!". Everything else is a warning

Answer (score 0):

Because you typed

```
npm install @ material-ui / core
```

instead of

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

npm went and tried to install the packages `@`, `material-ui`, `/` and `core`. Because `@` on its own is an invalid tag name, it threw that error. To undo what you've done, you need to execute:

```
npm uninstall material-ui core
```

and then

```
npm install @material-ui/core --save-dev
```